# Configuring timer jobs in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, timer-jobs, information-management, retention

I have setup Information Management policies and have added retention stages but to run that and verify I need to run the "Information management policy" and "Expiration policy" timer jobs.

Is it possible to view and configure these timer jobs in office 365/SharePoint Online.

**EDIT**

Since this isn't possible, Is there any chance to know on which day of the week these jobs are scheduled to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to configure (change schedule, trigger, etc.) timer jobs in SharePoint Online.

The best thing you can do is to make sure your policy settings are good and wait for jobs to be completed. :)

Comment: haha... I will wait then. is it possible to know when these timer jobs are configured to be run, like on which day or something?

Comment: According to this article [Create and apply information management policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9) it runs weekly. _Information management policies are compiled by an Information Management Policy Timer Job, managed by Microsoft, which runs weekly. Therefore, your policies may not take effect immediately. The frequency and date of the Information Management Policy Timer Job cannot be changed_

Comment: Our testing showed it was on Saturday in our tenant, but there's no guarantee that it will be the same for you, and MS won't give you a definitive date or time. Expect files to be deleted up to 2 weeks after you'd expect them to be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to check when it last ran and based on that you can deduce when's next run is likely to be.

Open up the SharePoint Online site collection in SharePoint Designer 2013 and go to Site Options. The properties below are of your interest.

```
dlc_PolicyUpdateLastRun
dlc_ExpirationLastRun
```

I've used this to test retentions policies before in SPO. 
In fact, when I tested couple times I figured out that for a newly created site collection, these jobs ran within 24 hours. But that was few months back.

Something is better than nothing. Good Luck.